# Como identificar o cliente pela chave pública de um certificado

Tags: segurança, criptografia, ssl, openssl

Como identifico o cliente X, cliente Y e o cliente Z quando eles tentam se autenticar via API...
Exemplo... um tal cliente me envia a chave uy2395734asdfas, como faço para saber que esse cliente é respectivamente o cliente Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somente com a chave-pública isso é impossível. Na verdade é possível, mas qualquer um pode alegar ser "Cliente Y", mesmo que não seja.

---

> Um tal cliente me envia a chave uy2395734asdfas, como faço para saber que esse cliente é respectivamente o cliente Y?

Se você só tem a chave pública, o que você tem é o mesmo que um token. Essa chave pública vai estar associada ao "Cliente Y", num banco de dados do tipo:

```
Cliente   | Chave
Cliente Y | uy2395734asdfas
Cliente X | aa3342131ssaxsd
```

Você não tem qualquer garantia criptográfica, portanto as tags da sua pergunta de `criptografia`, `ssl` e `openssl` podem ser ignoradas.

---

Se você quer identificar o usuário e saber se **ele é realmente o possuidor da chave-privada correspondente a chave-publica**, você tem que "testar"/"desafiar" (key-challenge ou challenge–response authentication). Como disse acima, qualquer pessoa poderia enviar uma requisição usando a chave-publica `uy2395734asdfas`. Para impedir isso você precisa requer uma prova de que realmente a pessoa que está requisitando tem a respectiva chave-privada.

Supondo que, por exemplo, esteja usando EdDSA/ECDSA, a cada requisição o cliente deveria de ASSINAR o corpo da requisição. Ela também deve conter a própria chave-publica.

Dessa forma você verifica a assinatura contra a chave-publica; e verifica no banco de dados se existe alguém associado à esta chave-pública. O seu problema aqui será mitigar um `replay-attack`, para isso pode adicionar um `expires` ou `nonce` afim de impedir re-uso de assinaturas.

---

No meu website, que utilizo Ed25519, o que eu faço é bem simples, existe um header:

```
X-Signature: [assinatura]
```

Todas as requisições devem ser feitas usando um padrão de:

```
{"public_key": [chave publica], "expires": [tempo para expirar], [resto do corpo]}
```

Dessa forma, simplesmente verifico se a assinatura é válida e não expirada, depois verifico se ele existe no banco de dados. O "expires" é menos eficiente do que um "nonce", mas é mais conveniente porque permite poupar a geração de assinaturas.

Esta técnica tem um problema com o método GET, mas não utilizo GET, então não há problema, mas é apenas o que uso, não o que deve usar (ou recomendado à usar).

---

Você também pode usar o método de desafio somente ao efetuar o login, isso é: você cria um desafio (n-bytes aleatórios) e pede para assinar, afim de provar que ele tem a chave-privada correspondente. Se tudo estiver certo você cria uma sessão tradicional, não precisando envolver a assinatura em todas as requisições.

---

Já que sua pergunta tem a tag de `ssl` e `openssl`... Existe uma outra forma usando o próprio SSL/TLS, que pode ser complexo dependendo da linguagem que está usando, mas é mais robusto.

Este método é conhecido como o `TLS Peer Authentication`. Primeiro, você cria um certificado que agirá como uma autoridade certificadora, gerando os certificados para os clientes (você não precisa da chave privada para gerar os certificados).

Para o cliente, em cada requisição, será necessário usar o certificado, nele conterá a chave pública no qual poderá associar ao "Cliente Y". Toda a validação dos certificados e assinaturas será feita na mesma camada do TLS, o que reduz a probabilidade de alguma implantação errada de sua parte. No Golang, por exemplo, pode obter as informações do certificado do cliente usando o [`ConnectionState.PeerCertificates`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ConnectionState).